# How to configure Partner Community where individual Users work for multiple Companies?

Tags: community, partner-communities

If the same User(Contact) works for multiple Companies(Accounts), How would you build for this scenario? Has anyone encountered this?

We are thinking of requiring those people to log in with different credentials when selling for different companies. Are that caveats to that approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Different User account and different credentials is poor UX and it leads to higher operational cost but easier to implement. Good UX would be single User account where transactional context (whatever they do in SF) is based on them selecting an Account. That latter step can be done via Login Flow, for example.These kind of problems need to be tackled as experience-first, technology second.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps needed, it seems:

This says that it is possible to do sharing via the AccountContactRelation object, letting Community users see multiple accounts based on that object:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_sharing_sets_contacts_multiple.htm

There is a feature in Community setup called Enable Account Relationships.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_partner_account_relationships_and_sharing.htm

This seems to be a good feature, but I haven't fully explored it, but it appears that you may need to enable that Account Relationships feature in Communities Settings to expose the AccountContactRelation-based sharing, since I didn't enable it, I do have that AccountContactRelation object in my org, and I don't get the sharing screen that's in the release notes.

So short answer: In a sandbox, check that box and try sharing via the AccountContactRelation object